# How to extract the values from the ansible output using with_items/loops

Tags: ansible

Trying to use below lines of codes

```
- name: reconstruct the path to test
    set_fact: 
      folder_check: "{{ item | join('\\\\') }}"
      # | regex_replace('\\\\', ',') 
    with_items:
      - "{{ path_list }}"
    ignore_errors: yes  
    register: output
```

When I execute this part of code, I get below output for SET_FACT task and not the output of Registered output var.

```
ok: [shancamw2k12.iafdomain.local] => (item=[u'C:', u'temp', u'temp1']) => {"ansible_facts": {"folder_check": "C:\\\\temp\\\\temp1"}, "changed": false, "item": ["C:", "temp", "temp1"]}
ok: [shancamw2k12.iafdomain.local] => (item=[u'C:', u'temp']) => {"ansible_facts": {"folder_check": "C:\\\\temp"}, "changed": false, "item": ["C:", "temp"]}
ok: [shancamw2k12.iafdomain.local] => (item=[u'C:']) => {"ansible_facts": {"folder_check": "C:"}, "changed": false, "item": ["C:"]}.
```

From this lines I should just extract `"folder_check": "C:\\\\temp\\\\temp1" ; "C:\\\\temp" and C:\\`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and format your code correctly ? There are formatting aids at the right of the editing scree. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the value of path_list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am assuming a few things based on the content and format of your question.

1. The list being provided to the to variable building task will be in the order you want and does not need to be sorted.
2. You will always be using all of them
3. That you are doing this because the number of items (and their content) being fed into the set_fact task will not be static
4. The number of slashes trailing C is
   different depending on if it is by itself or if it is accompanied by
   other parts of the path.

Also, since you are setting a fact, you don't need to save it to a register unless you need other meta data about the building of the variable other than its output.

```
- name: Build Variable
  hosts:
    - all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    - path_list:
        - "C:"
        - "temp"
        - "temp1"
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        temp_var: "{{ temp_var|default([]) + [ item + ('//' if my_idx == 0 else '' if my_idx == path_list|length - 1 else '////') ] }}"
      loop: "{{ path_list }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx

    - set_fact:
        folder_check: "{{ folder_check|default([]) + [ item if my_idx|int-1 < 0 else folder_check[my_idx|int-1] + '//' + item if my_idx|int-1 == 0 else folder_check[my_idx|int-1] + item  ] }}"
      loop: "{{ temp_var }}"
      loop_control:
        index_var: my_idx

    - debug: var=folder_check
```

Which will give you output like this:

```
PLAY [Build Variable] ********************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=C:) => {"ansible_facts": {"temp_var": ["C://"]}, "changed": false, "item": "C:", "my_idx": 0}
ok: [host1] => (item=temp) => {"ansible_facts": {"temp_var": ["C://", "temp////"]}, "changed": false, "item": "temp", "my_idx": 1}
ok: [host1] => (item=temp1) => {"ansible_facts": {"temp_var": ["C://", "temp////", "temp1"]}, "changed": false, "item": "temp1", "my_idx": 2}

TASK [set_fact] **************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => (item=C://) => {"ansible_facts": {"folder_check": ["C://"]}, "changed": false, "item": "C://", "my_idx": 0}
ok: [host1] => (item=temp////) => {"ansible_facts": {"folder_check": ["C://", "C:////temp////"]}, "changed": false, "item": "temp////", "my_idx": 1}
ok: [host1] => (item=temp1) => {"ansible_facts": {"folder_check": ["C://", "C:////temp////", "C:////temp////temp1"]}, "changed": false, "item": "temp1", "my_idx": 2}

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************************
ok: [host1] => {
    "folder_check": [
        "C://",
        "C:////temp////",
        "C:////temp////temp1"
    ]
}
```